# Append <options> to <select> using AJAX & PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database

I have two tables in my database:

**1.** Animal types 
**2.** Breeds

**animal_type:**

```
type_id  |    name
------------------------
1        |  Dog
2        |  Cat
3        |  etc...
```

**breed**

```
ID   |  type_id |  name 
---------------------------
1    |    1     | Labrador
2    |    1     | Putbull
3    |    2     | Persian
etc.....
```

On my front page I want to show select dropdown menu with animal types and breeds select based on animal type.

**1. Select animal type**

```
<select id="animal_type">
   <option value="<?php $type->id">Dog</option>
   <option value="<?php $type->id">Cat</option>
</select>
```

**2. If user select type undisable select list with breeds based on type**

```
<!-- user select Dog type!  fetch all dog breeds -->
<select id="breeds" disabled>
   <option value="<?php $type->id">Labrador</option>
   <option value="<?php $type->id">Pitbull</option>
</select>
```

So I want to load all breeds from my controller based on witch type is selected. I try to slove this with ajax but am not realy good with him.
I try this and dont know how to append new option to select dropdown.

**Script :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   // $("#breeds").attr('disabled', true);

    // check if selected
    if($("#animal_type").find('option:selected').val() == 0) {
        $("#breeds").attr('disabled', true);
    }

    $('#animal_type').change(function(){
        // get value of selected animal type
        var selected_animal_type = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

        $.ajax({
            url : "url-to-site/index.php/account/getBreedsByTypeID/1",
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                $("#breeds").attr('disabled', false);

                //alert(response); // show [object, Object]

                var $select = $('#breeds');

                $select.find('option').remove();
                $.each(response,function(key, value)
                {
                    $select.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>'); // return empty
                });
             }
        });
    });
 });
```

**JSON returns**  my custom breed names

```
[{"breed_name":"Nema\u010dki prepeli\u010dar"},{"breed_name":"Irski vodeni \u0161panijel"},{"breed_name":"Barbe (Barbet)"},{"breed_name":"Lagoto 
My controller `mysite.com/index.php/account/getBreedsByTypeID/1`
```

This url returns the following encoded JSON

```
$breeds = $this->animal_breed->findAllBreedsByType($id); // Model @return array

return json_encode($breeds);
```

So how can I append that result to my select based on type?

Could you offer an example to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You are missing the `data` parameter in your `$.ajax` request, try adding `data:{ id: selected_animal_type }`. Also, are you sure that URL is correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
            url : "url-to-site/index.php/account/getBreedsByTypeID/1",
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                $("#breeds").attr('disabled', false);
                $.each(response,function(key, value)
                {
                    $("#breeds").append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
                });
             }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
        url : "url-to-site/index.php/account/getBreedsByTypeID/1",
      data:{id:selected_animal_type},             
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            $("#breeds").attr('disabled', false);
            $.each(response,function(key, value)
            {
                $("#breeds").append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value.breed_name + '</option>');
            });
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#departmentId").change(function() {
  console.log($("#departmentId").children("option:selected").val());
  console.log(getAllOfficeByDepartmentId($("#departmentId").children("option:selected").val()));
});

function getAllOfficeByDepartmentId(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "getofficebydepartment/" + id,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      $("#officeId").find('option').remove();
      $("#officeId").append('<option value="-1" selected>Select Office Name</option>');
      $.each(response, function (key, value) {
        $("#officeId").append('<option value="'+ value.officeId+'">' + value.officeName+'</option>');
      });
    },
    error: function (err) {
      alert("Error" + err);
    }
  });
}
```

*Compare with yours.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.