# Add more select fields generated by php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a select field on HTML page filled by PHP, from MySQL db.

```
echo "<select name='author_id[]' size='1'>";

foreach ($authors as $author) {
    echo "<option value=$author[id]>$author[last_name]</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
```

How I can leverage JavaScript here to add more fields? Which will use also php to list all authors.

For example if book have multiple authors, user can press button like:

```
<button title='Press for add author.' onclick='addBookAuthor()'>More authors</button>
```

JS:

```
addBookAuthor() {
    ... to be done))
}
```

How JS function should looks like? I know JS can add text to already exists HTML fields, but in my case HTML dynamically generated by PHP... which is little confusing me.

Want that in the end all added authors will be available in `$_POST['author_id']` array

Comment: This Q&A should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651802/append-options-to-select-using-ajax-php

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61628313/ajax-response-append-to-select-options

Comment: They are good, but is it possible do that without AJAX/jQuery?

Comment: Remember that php is what accesses the data and builds the html/js. When the html/js is handed over to the browser, php (and all data lookup) is done, and php is out of the picture. So approach the problem from an html/js viewpoint: do you need data that is not being displayed by html?  You either need to request it via ajax or already have the info in a javascript data structure in the page that was served. The latter is certainly possible, but usually is far more information than you want to send. ajax is a far better solution in most applications.

Comment: You are right, php will be not accessible when user will be hitting button, my bad. Need add select option with data already displayed, just multiple it. As I described it is list of authors, add more list of authors if book have 1> authors. Probably multiple attribute of select can help, but it looks weird with 4 size and no scroll, so is no way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clone()` method to clone your first select-box which is generated by php code then append same select-box in your *DOM* .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function addBookAuthor() {
  //get first select-box clone it
  var cloned = $("select[name*=author_id]:first").clone();
  $("#add").append($(cloned)) //add that in your dom..
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<button title='Press for add author.' onclick='addBookAuthor()'>More authors</button>

<div id="add">
  <!--suppose this is html genrated of php code -->
  <select name='author_id[]' size='1'>
    <option value=1>A</option>
    <option value=2>B</option>
    <option value=3>C</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also did this without using jQuery, only by JavaScript:

```
function addAuthorField() {
    var author = document.getElementById('author_id');
    var parent = author.parentNode;
    var author_cloned = author.cloneNode(true);
    parent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    parent.appendChild(author_cloned);
}
```

Correct please, if you see any errors.